# Как переопределить текст ошибок формы Django?

Tags: django

Использую PasswordResetConfirmView. Хочу поменять текст ошибок, как это можно  сделать?

**url.py**

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>',
     authViews.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="mainApp/password_reset_form.html"),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

**шаблон**

```
{% extends 'wrapper.html' %}
{% block content%}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Восстановление пароля</h1>
        <h6>
          Пожалуйста, введите новый пароль
        </h6>
      </div>
      <br />
      <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="password"
               class="form-control"
               name="new_password1"
               required=""
               placeholder="Пароль"
               id="id_new_password1"
               aria-autocomplete="list">
        <input type="password"
               class="form-control mt-1"
               name="new_password2"
               required=""
               placeholder="Повторите пароль"
               id="id_new_password2">
        {% if form.errors %}
          {{ form.errors }}
        {% endif %}
        <input class="btn btn-light mt-2" type="submit" value="Сбросить пароль">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock%}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: рассмотрите класс `SetPasswordForm`

Comment: спасибо, помогло)